# Load undefined component via ajax with vue3 after app instancing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I would like to know which is the way to load an new component inside vue3 app instance. As far as I know its only possible to use components predefined during createApp() or via some internal trickery even after initialization but never on runtime after use.

The problem is than I cant find a way to fetch the component at runtime, via an ajax call so instead of throwing "Failed to resolve component: mycomponent" it would check the server and import the component.

Yes, I know about defineAsyncComponent and vue3-sfc-loader but none of them seem to handle undefined components. They all seem to require the definition of all the components that we will be using. Or no?

```
var vapp = Vue.createApp({

    template: '<mycomponent></mycomponent>',
    components: {} /** not defined at runtime **/,

    _importUndefinedComponent: function(tagname) { 
        $.get('/components/' + tagname + '.js'); 
    }
});
```

For now I think that it's possible to edit the internal workings of Vue, as it seems that vue already uses promises to load async components....

A usecase for dynamic components. I have an crud system with hundreds of components. I want to make quick prototypes. So this way all I have to do is just upload the component to the right folder an use it. No build step and no fancy stuff. All components are using options api. So basically it's just an Object which I will eval.

Comment: AJAX isn't intended to load scripts. Consider explaining your case. Whatever you try to do, it's not done like that. If a component is dynamic, use dynamic components https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components

Comment: Dynamic components require to make a list of all the components. In my current context its not efficient for many reasons. Loading those would be more flexible and efficient for my use case. Actually I have another library that loads js components dynamically and want to keep the same functionallity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As long as you have a component in a variable, you can do `<component :is="variable">`. Any way, you're putting yourself into corner case. This isn't how Vue is typically used and it doesn't work the way you want with undefined comps. "as it seems that vue already uses promises to load async components" - but they should be known beforehands, this is important for a compiler. I'm not sure what prevents you from specifying the right components in `components`. If you need do load them asynchronously then delay app init until they are loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using `:is=` to load the right component. I'm have a script that generates the list of components too. But I kinda need to create a loader, as there are folders manged by differnt people that have no access to the main project. I need to make it work kinda like requirejs does.

Comment: There's SystemJS for this purpose

Comment: Gonna look into it, thanks